# Why can't subclasses override 'private' base method in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm currently stunned by some Python behavior:

```
class Base(object):
    def foo(self):
        self.__virtual_function()
        self.virtual_function()
    def __virtual_function(self):
        print("private Base")
    def virtual_function(self):
        print("public Base")

class Derived(Base):
    def __virtual_function(self):
        print("private Derived")
    def virtual_function(self):
        print("public Derived")

d = Derived()
d.foo()
```

This prints

```
private Base
public Derived
```

Is the double underscore *effectively* making a method private, and thus not overridable by subclasses?

Comment: Dupe explains it well, there is a name mangling under the hood.

Comment: While the double-underscore does effectively make an attribute "private", it wasn't designed to that. See [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg&t=33m8s) by Raymond Hettinger. Stick around for the discussion of getters/setters and properties, if you are coming from C++.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it doesn't make anything private, I found out, it rather serves as an identifier for (non-overridable) class methods.